# Create a WebSocket with a dynamic path using a WebWorker which is in a javascript type BLOB

Tags: javascript, web-worker

How can I open a new WebSocket which is inside a javascript type BLOB WebWorker using a path that is dynamic?

```
let DYNAMIC_PATH = 'ws://localhost'; // dynamically changing

let ww = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([
  var ws = new WebSocket(DYNAMIC_PATH); // <-- HOT TO GET THIS VARIABLE

  self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      console.log('@@', event.data);
  }, false);
  ], { type: 'application/javascript' }));

sendToWW = function (data) {
  ww.postMessage(data);
};
```

Comment: WebSocket or WebWorker...

Comment: You are right. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a value to function by creating parameter.

```
let DYNAMIC_PATH = 'ws://localhost'; // dynamically changing

let ww = (DYNAMIC_PATH)=> URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([
var ws = new WebSocket(DYNAMIC_PATH); // <-- HOT TO GET THIS VARIABLE

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  console.log('@@', event.data);
}, false);
], { type: 'application/javascript' }));

sendToWW = function (DYNAMIC_PATH,data) {
ww(DYNAMIC_PATH).postMessage(data);
};
```